# Why is my Xcode CPU usage so high?

Tags: xcode

For some reason, Xcode's (7.3.1) auto complete is causing my CPU usage to go high. It will go up to 300%, and even not respond. If I don't kill it quick enough, it affects my whole computer. I tested it on another project to see if it was some snippet of code that I had written out, but it still happens on other projects. It's find when I turn off autocomplete (as I'm typing). The autocomplete when pressing ESC is okay to use.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have the same problem where Xcode 8.2.1 is using all of my Mac's CPU.